# Is it mandatory to have Sharepoint for publishing and distribution of reports developed using Power BI

Tags: sharepoint, data-visualization, powerbi

I have this requirement:

`Is it mandatory to have Sharepoint for publishing and distribution of reports developed using Power BI`

Please guide me on this,I googled about but no results.

Some examples would be really appreciated.

Comment: In the cloud, with www.PowerBI.com, you don't need to use SharePoint to publish and distribute reports.   However, you can, if you choose to, use Office 365 SharePoint in conjunction with PowerBI.  On premises, you can build reports in two ways: SQL Server Reporting Services or Power View.  SSRS comes in Native mode that does not require SharePoint or SharePoint Integrated mode that, does.  On premises Power View requires SharePoint.

Comment: Let me add a link to how to share a dashboard through PowerBI.com.  http://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/431008-share-and-unshare-a-dashboard-from-power-bi

Answer (score 0):

Yikes - looks like my answer went into the comments :).  Check out how to share through Power BI here: http://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/431008-share-and-unshare-a-dashboard-from-power-bi